# UITextField shouldChangeCharactersinRange as external function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

I want to validate UITextField input for multiple view controllers.  The following works:

validate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface validate : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

validate.m

```
#import "validate.h"

@implementation validate
```

viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "limiteTextField.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet limiteTextField *myTextField;
@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController  

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 //my code for validating 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myTextField.delegate=self;
```

I want to be able to use the shouldChangeCharactersInRange as an external function so don't have to rewrite all its code for each view controller.

Comment: Create a custom class of text field and set it to every text field of view controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to create some kind of validator class with a singleton and assigning it as the textfields delegate:

**TextFieldValidator.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TextFieldValidator : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>

+ (instancetype)sharedValidator;

@end
```

**TextFieldValidator.m**

```
#import "TextFieldValidator.h"

@implementation TextFieldValidator

+ (instancetype)sharedValidator {
    static TextFieldValidator *sharedValidator = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedValidator = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedValidator;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    return [[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:allowedCharacters.invertedSet].location == NSNotFound;
}

@end
```

**SomeViewController.m**

```
// [...]

self.textField.delegate = [TextFieldValidator sharedValidator];

// [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to use the shouldChangeCharactersInRange as an external function so don't have to rewrite all its code for each view controller.

Then do so. This is a delegate method. Anything can be the delegate. You are the one who is setting the text field's delegate to be different view controllers! If you don't want to do that, then don't. Have some single persistent object, or at least multiple instance of the same class, and make *that* the delegate of the text field. Now all text fields can use this same delegate which has just one implementation of `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Comment: I should have asked re best way of doing this - am relatively ignorant-

Comment: Well, that's why I gave you a solution.